# Url rewrite not work in wamp localhost

Tags: seo, htaccess, php

I am developing a PHP web application. I have pages, posts, categories, product and etc.

Here is my `.htaccess` file to create SEO friendly URL:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Page/(.*)/(.*)$ Page.php?Page_Id=$1&Page_Title=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Product/(.*)/(.*)$ Product.php?Product_Id=$1&Product_Title=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Category/(.*)/(.*)$ Category.php?Category_Id=$1&Category_Title=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Single/(.*)/(.*)$ Single.php?Post_Id=$1&Post_Title=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Blog/(.*)/(.*)$ Blog.php?Category_Id=$1&Category_Title=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]


<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

When I visit `Page.php?Page_Id=13` it works. And also when I visit `Page/13/Page-Title` it works. Everything is good when I test my application on the server, but it doesn't work in wamp localhost.

I active

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

in Apache `http.conf` and here is my vhost:

```
    <VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName schoolarshop
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/schoolarshop"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/schoolarshop/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride none
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Example of error in localhost is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Page_Id in Page.php on line 8
```

Why does it work on the server and not in localhost?

I Googled a lot but it can't find anything.

Comment: Using WordPress? you need to update the site URL and permalinks.

Comment: no i use pure php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
> ```

Why are you explicitly enabling `MultiViews` in your server config? This is likely the cause of your problem. Try removing `+MultiViews` from your server config (above), and/or disable MultiViews at the top of your `.htaccess`:

```
 Options -Indexes -MultiViews
```

MutliViews is disabled on a default Apache install, however, some (shared) hosts do seem to enable it. So, disabling it in `.htaccess` as a matter of course is probably recommended.

(But also, why are you enabling `Includes` - is this really necessary? Since you are using PHP, this is unlikely.)

The effect of MultiViews is noticeable because you have effectively removed the file extension to create your user-friendly URLs.

With MultiViews enabled (part of mod_negotiation)... when you request `Page/13/Page-Title`, Apache tries to find a matching file in the current/root directory that matches the basename `Page`, by trying various extensions that would return the appropriate mime-type. This occurs *before* mod_rewrite is able to rewrite your friendly URL. So, MultiViews ends up rewriting your request to `Page.php` without passing any of the URL params (the rest of the URL will likely be seen as PATH_INFO), hence your "Undefined index" PHP notice.

(Although you should also be checking for the existence of this `$_GET` variable in your PHP script, which you don't seem to be doing.)

Comment: thanks.it work but now i have anither problem.when i visit Page/13/page-title if the lenght of page title is less than 5 it work but for more than 5 character it shows The requested URL Page/13/blah-blah-blah-blah  was not found on this server.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in your `.htaccess` file that would be dependent on the page title length. (_Everything_ after the second slash is simply passed through to the `Page_Title` URL param.) Examine the URL parameters that `Page.php` is receiving - are these as expected?
 However, I would not expect the page title to control which page is returned either - I would expect the `Page_Id` to control this?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/schoolarshop/Page/13/قوانین-و-مقررات` the top url shows error but `http://localhost:8080/schoolarshop/Page/13/قوانین`works

Comment: Maybe a character encoding or application logic problem in your server-side PHP/DB code? As mentioned, there's nothing in the code you have posted (Apache directives) that would explain this. What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: sorry i do it in a wrong way.i change  `RewriteRule ^Page/(.*)/(.*)$`  to   `RewriteRule ^Page/([\s\S]*)/([\s\S]*)$`  and it worked.thank you for your answers